# How to add Forgotten Password text in Login with redirect to other page in Yii2

Tags: authentication, passwords, yii2, forgot-password

I need some help how to put the "Forgotten Password" to Login page to redirect to the page I want to go to after its clicked

Comment: Do you need help to create a link? `<a href="yourForgotPasswordUrl">Forgot password?</a>`

Comment: `<?= Html::a(Yii::t('site', 'Forgotten Password?'), ['controller/action-name'], ['class' => 'text-center']) ?>`

Comment: it should be page in my project that is redirected ,so <a href> dont work

Comment: @InsaneSkull this "site" string should be pointing at ? (sry for maybe the stupid question" but I`m new at Yii2)

Comment: site is your controller name and if you have `actionForgottenPassword` then `['site/forgotten-password]`.

Comment: <?= Html::a(Yii::t('site/ChangePassword', 'Forgotten Password?'), ['controllers/SiteController'], ['class' => 'text-center']) ?>
it should be like that , but throw me " Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
Unable to locate message source for category 'site/ChangePassword'."

Comment: `<?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Forgotten Password?'), ['site/change-password'], ['class' => 'text-center']) ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Forgotten Password?'), 
           ['site/change-password'], 
           ['class' => 'text-center']) 
?>
```

In `site` Controller :

```
public function actionChangePassword()
{
   return $this->render('ChangePassword');
}
```

Comment: It give me error that I cant find the page now... Any Idea ? (its already made "ChangePassword.php" page)
<?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Forgotten Password?'), ['/site/ChangePassword'], ['class' => 'text-center']) ?>